# Error: invalid use of 'void' (using vectors)

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a code using vectors and other c++11 utilities. The above mentioned(on the title) error occurs in my code and despite I looked for a solution to this error on the internet I did not find something that works into my code. I tried to make some type castings but did not work. I present you the contentious part of code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
//#include <Winbase.h>

using namespace std;

// A struct describing a product.
typedef struct Products
{
    string category;
    string name;
    float price;
} Product;

inline void scenario1(int num_cashiers)
{
    vector<Product> products; // It is a vector(a pseudo-second dimension) of products which will be used for each customer
    vector<vector<Product>> customers; // A vector containing all customers
    vector<vector<vector<Product>>> cashiers(num_cashiers); // A vector describing the supermarket cashiers declaring a queue of customers for each cashier
    double start = GetTickCount(); // It will be used for counting 10 secs until next update
    vector<int> total_products(num_cashiers); // A vector keeping the total number of products of each queue
    list<string> categories; // A list containing all the categories of the products
    list<float> categories_prices(categories.unique().size()); // A list containing all category prices
    //THE ABOVE LINE - THE LAST ONE IN THIS PART OF CODE - IS THE LINE I GET THE ERROR!!!
    ....

}
```

What is wrong with the code?

Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: Well, [`std::list::unique()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/unique) has `void` as return type. You cannot do any further dereferncing?`

Comment: Read the docs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/unique

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would like a list which will keep for each and every category the amount that the customers of the supermarket spent on their products. But, firstly, I want to reserve the necessary space for the categories_prices list. This size is the size of the categories list (which includes the name of all available categories of products that a supermarket has - and this list is unique, I do not care for the duplicates). But I am doing something wrong by implementing it.

Comment: @FredLarson I have read this documentation, so what? What exactly would  you like me to take into consideration?

Comment: @Jimbo_ai return type

Comment: `void` is nothing. Nothing has no `size()` to call. What `unique` is doing is removing repetition from `categories`, effectively destroying your data. Not what you want.

Answer (score 8):

list::unique is a void function, it does not return anything. On that last line, where you call categories.unique().size(), you are calling .size() on a void expression.

Comment: So, in case I wrote firstly categories.unique() and then reserved the necessary space for my list through categories_prices.reserve(categories.size()) would it be a solution?

Comment: Almost. `unique` only removes repetition. `unique` will turn 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 into 1 2 3 4 3 2 1. But if you sort the list first....